# Ember camelize() vs javaScript camelize()

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to camelize an extracted value from an ember view, and I was hoping to get the lower case camelized form of a string as is written here http://docs.emberjs.com/symbols/Ember.String.html#.camelize

However, what I'm getting back is the capitalized version of it (the extracted value started off as Capitalized).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that `My-Lovely-Property` isn't converted to `myLovelyProperty`. Nor is `MY-LOVELY-PROPERTY` -- it leaves those "OVELY" "ROPERTY" caps alone too and yields `MYLOVELYPROPERTY` which certainly doesn't feel like camel case. I'm not sure if that behavior is intended or not, but it seems neither this case nor yours is covered by the test examples.

If you or anyone else believes strongly that such cases should be covered in some way, perhaps submit a github issue or PR? Otherwise, for the case you describe you can use an expression like `str.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + str.substr(1).camelize()`.

Comment: I must have been confusing it with another example from another language then, I saw the text "Returns the lowerCaseCamel form of a string." and thought it would behave in the manner described. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this `Ember.String.camelize("my lovely property")` which gives you `myLovelyProperty`